# UniRx SchedulerOn MainThread not works at first time invoke

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine, system.reactive

I heavily use UniRx in my project but I find a problem when I first call `SchedulerOn(Scheduler.MainThread)` it will NOT do left things in main thread.Uses code like this:

```
Login (new LoginReq (account.text, pwd.text, 1L)).SchedulerOn(Scheduler.MainThread).Done (x => {
    Debug.Log("login req thread - " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Package.Log("Login response - " + x.ToString());
    if(x.errorMsg == null) {
        Package.Log("login success - " + x.ToString());
        //choice game world -> choice role
        enterObj.SetActive(true);
        loginObj.SetActive(false);
    } else {
        rspTips.text = x.ToString();
    }
});
```

The output shows SetActive only can be call at main thread.
The problem occurred expecially when I open PC and first run the application.
Does it because of .NET warm up? I'm not sure how does the thread dispatch works.

**UPDATE**
I think I'm loss some important things.
`Login` return `RSG.IPromise<T>`([git home page at here](https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise)) which used to lightweight asyc task but `RSG.Promise` lib doesn't have scheduler module.So I'm wrap a `SchedulerPromise` with `UniRx`'s `IScheduler` and the code not has novel technology.[See this please about the wrapper source code](https://github.com/LoranceChen/MiniMoTank/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Util/Promise/SheduleredPromise.cs#L159)

I have stuck here a long time.Thanks any advice.

Comment: In what library/namespace does `SchedulerOn` actually exist?

Comment: @supertopi, it equals `SubscribeOn`, sorry not explain this.I add a detail at **UPDATE**

Comment: If I try and call Unity code from an obvserver I get 'can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.'
Unless I put `.ObserveOnMainThread()`

Comment: @sentece, yes, you are right. I have fix my problem on the lastest push history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UniRx runs its scheduling on separate threads, but Unity is single threaded and not thread-safe. It prevents code that accesses its object from running on a separate thread.

UniRX provides a method to join the subscription to the observable onto its main thread to allow running code that accesses Unity objects:

`.ObserveOnMainThread()`

Comment: My `SchedulerOn` wrap a false dispatch of `UniRx`'s Scheduler.The `ObserveOnMainThread` is very helpful~